# Any fixes for Twitter Bootstrap in Opera Mini?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently took up Twitter Bootstrap 3 to make interfaces rapidly. I mistakenly assumed it would work well in Opera Mobile.Opera 8 works okay but newer versions like 12 aren't working so well. The glyphicons and image in the jumbotron aren't loading well.Any fixes I can implement?

Comment: Regarding Glyphicons, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22456632/3342739

Comment: Also, try upgrading to Opera Mobile 16, which is actually officially supported by Bootstrap.